# Use jQuery to populate sibling hidden input

Tags: jquery, html, input

For a calculation with currencies, I need the value of an input to be parsed as an integer and this value should populate the sibling input of type "hidden".

I would like to make this as reusable as possible, to use the same script for all inputs like it.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="input-group" id="total-emplcosts">
   <span class="input-group-addon">Total employer costs</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="empl_costs_inp" id="empl_costs_inp" />
   <input type="hidden" name="empl_costs" id="empl_costs" />
</div>
```

**JQuery**
What I tried: (Not doing anything at all)

```
$('.input-group input').on('keyup blur focusout',function() {
    if($(this).val() !== '') {
                var inputValue = $(this).val();
                var integerValue = parseInt(inputValue * 100);
                $('input').siblings('input').val(integerValue);
    }
}
```

and: (Adding the integerValue to all hidden inputs)

```
$('.input-group input').on('keyup blur focusout',function() {
    if($(this).val() !== '') {
                var inputValue = $(this).val();
                var integerValue = parseInt(inputValue * 100);
                $('input').next('input[type=hidden]').val(integerValue);
    }
}
```

I think I'm quite close to the solution, but I need a nodge in the right direction.

Comment: $(this) ?? what is $(this) .. please provide html and js event full code

Comment: can you provide your html and full code

Comment: How could we help witout seeing any relevant HTML markup nor context regarding `this`???

Comment: Sorry for giving too little details.. Added HTML and jQuery events

Comment: `$(this).siblings('input[type=text]').val(integerValue);`

Comment: Would that target the hidden input?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
var integerValue = parseInt(inputValue * 100);
```

to

```
var integerValue = parseInt(inputValue) * 100;
```

Basically you parse `inputValue` first before multiplying

Also

1. you missed `)` at the end
2. it would be much better if you declared your variables outside of
   the function, so that they won't be created every time the event
   fires

Your script would look like this

```
var inputValue,
integerValue;
$('.input-group input').on('keyup blur focusout',function() {
    if($(this).val() !== '') {
        inputValue = $(this).val();
        integerValue = parseInt(inputValue) * 100;
        $('input:text').siblings('input:hidden').val(integerValue);
    }
});
```

---

Regarding your comment, You can use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`.

Also you **cannot** multiply `number` by `string` in javascript. You have to *parse* before performing the mathematical operation.

---

**Edit 2**

This is your `HTML`

```
<div class="input-group" id="rate">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Rate per day/hour</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rate_inp" id="calc_rate_inp" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rate" id="calc_rate" />
</div>
<div class="input-group" id="bill-costs">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Billable costs</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bill_costs_inp" id="bill_costs_inp" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bill_costs" id="bill_costs" />
</div>
```

Now, this part of your script `$('.input-group input')`, selects every `input` in every `.input-group`, and you have 2 `.input-group`, so that's why you get both of your `input:hidden` *selected*.

To fix this, you can use `$(this)`.

So basically change this line `$('input:text').siblings('input:hidden').val(integerValue);` to

```
$(this).siblings('input:hidden').val(integerValue);
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2g9onby/2/).

Comment: I was too quick to accept the answer. This doesn't work for decimal numbers. Can't I `* 100` before I parse the integer?

Comment: Okay, did that (parseFloat) but somehow every hidden input is seen as sibling. So all hidden inputs have the same value... But every input couple are children of a seperate div.

Comment: @MartijnICU Of course, because `siblings('input:hidden')` _selects_ all the siblings input hidden. If you want specific element, change the selector.

Comment: So siblings aren't relative to the parent element?

Comment: [Sibling elements are elements that share the same parent.](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_siblings.asp)

Comment: Okay, so to clarify; If there are multiple elements with children using the same class, all children of those elements are siblings? I can't explicitly find this in the documentation...

Comment: No, `sibilings()` get the siblings element of **the** parent. If you see unexpected result, you can make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Thank you, I made a fiddle, demonstrating the behaviour. https://jsfiddle.net/j2g9onby/

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying the concept of the .siblings function! You're a life-saver.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inputValue,
integerValue;
$('.input-group input').on('keyup blur focusout',function() {
    if($(this).val() !== '') {
        inputValue = $(this).val();
        integerValue = parseInt(inputValue) * 100;
        $(this).siblings('input:hidden').val(integerValue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `.parent()` method with find `input[type="hidden"]` in the current context:

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group" id="total-emplcosts">
   <span class="input-group-addon">Total employer costs</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="empl_costs_inp" id="empl_costs_inp" />
   <input type="hidden" name="empl_costs" id="empl_costs" />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.input-group input').on('keyup blur focusout',function() {
        if($(this).val() !== '') {
                    var inputValue = $(this).val();
                    var integerValue = parseInt(inputValue * 100);
                    $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"]').val(integerValue); // <-- Here find current object parent, then tell that parent to find it's child which is input hidden
        }
    })
});
```

You can check the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/touqeershafi/c3gpb3of/).

**Tip:** Inspect Element via Google Chrome Developer Tool to check value change of hidden field.